# Cleanup after MSTest unloaded the dlls?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am writing UnitTests for a Wrapper that encapsulates a dll I have not access to.

This dll will write files to a given location and holds a handle on them during the dll's entire lifetime.

After my UnitTests have run, I want to delete all the files that were written by the dll during the tests.

However, if I use the MSTest Attributes `[TestCleanup]` `[ClassCleanup]` or `[AssemblyCleanup]` , I am unable to delete all the files because the dll is still loaded and the its handle on the files still exists.

Is there a way to run the very last method after MSTest unloaded the testet dll?

Right now, I see only 2 possible solutions none of which sounds appealing:

- Create a Wrapper only to run the tests that encapsulates the testet Wrapper in a AppDomain
  which I can unload on `AssemblyCleanup` (a lot of work)
- Make unit tests save the paths to the written files and delete those files on the next Testrun (this will still leave me with garbage but at least this garbage does not interfere with the next run)

Comment: is this not a integration test scenario? Why dont you try to unload the dll in your testcase and then try deleting?

Comment: how do I unload an dll that I did not specifically put inside its own AppDomain?

Comment: read your question after edit, and can u pls tell me you are trying to write a unit test or integration test?